# Find all objects where value is undefined

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have my objects stored in `indexeddb`. I have an index on a text property on the object. I want to find all the objects, where the value of these is undefined.

I've been working with `IDBKeyRange.only(key)` however, if I pass `null` or `undefined` or string empty it throws `DataError: The parameter is not a valid key`. It works for all defined values however.

I've been using Chrome to test this.

**Update:**

Looking at the resources tab in the chrome I see that the values are not present in the index.  Thus with how my current index work it can't be used to find objects where the property is not set.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with secondary (index) key, use `IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(0)`. Note `null` or `undefined` are not valid [IDBKey](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#key-construct).

Comment: Didn't work, the best I got was all with values. I tried with both lower and upperBound. using '' and 0 as arguments, neither got the entries where there was no value.

Comment: I see. `IndexedDB.cmp` is not defined for `null` or `undefined`, so it won't pickup.